# How we can create a design background using the linear-gradient?

Tags: html, css, background, linear-gradients

I have the following design and I want to manage it using single background css attribute on single div tag.

[image]

I add the following code to make background as it in image but I am unable to manage it for footer.
HTML

```
<div class="main-container></div>
```

CSS

```
.main-container{
 linear-gradient(to right, #86aec1 0%, #86aec1 3.6%, #afafaf 3.6%, #afafaf 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 73.9%;
}
```

Using the above code it shows only left blue section and right gray section but I am unable to get any other option where i can create footer section on a single div.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Tm2rF/1/)? Not sure and hence not added as anwer.

Comment: Yes you great but I tried same but I want exact same design. You can see at the bottom there is gray space between the blue background. That thing is difficult to design. :(

Comment: True, we have to use a combo of box-shaow (inset) and the linear-gradient. And that gray area is there in the fiddle.

Comment: @Harry: Can you please write the css code for me as I am tried last night. It would be great help for me.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a mix of `box-shadow` and `linear-gradient`. Refer inline comments for more details.

```css
.main-container {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf 89%, #86aec1 89%, #afafaf 91%); /* this produces the thin line above the bottom */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf 89%, #86aec1 89%, #afafaf 91%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #afafaf 89%, #86aec1 89%, #afafaf 91%);
  /* Just play around with the percentages and increase them to get a thicker line */
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 73.9%;
  box-shadow: inset 25px -25px #86aec1; /* this produces the thick left and bottom border */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple backgrounds. In the following example, two linear gradients and one solid color background is used:

```css
.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right,
      rgba(133, 173, 192, 1)    0, rgba(133, 173, 192, 1) 20px,
      rgba(133, 173, 192, 0) 20px
    ),
    linear-gradient(to top,
      rgba(133, 173, 192, 1)    0, rgba(133, 173, 192, 1) 20px,
      rgba(133, 173, 192, 0) 20px, rgba(133, 173, 192, 0) 25px,
      rgba(133, 173, 192, 1) 25px, rgba(133, 173, 192, 1) 30px,
      rgba(133, 173, 192, 0) 30px
    ),
    #AFAFAF;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container"></div>
```